# minikube metallb external-ip vs minikube ip

Tags: minikube, metallb

[image]

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: metallb-system
  name: config
  labels:
    app: metallb

data:
  config: |
    address-pools:
    - name: default
      protocol: layer2
      addresses:
      - 192.168.99.100-192.168.99.250
```

Hello, I am using metallb in minikube (virtualbox). When configuring metallb's external-ip, you must set it according to the minikube ip range. But why does it work well even out of range?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is working as expected due to your [Layer 2 configuration of your MetalLB](https://metallb.universe.tf/configuration/):

> Layer 2 mode is the simplest to configure: in many cases, you don’t
> need any protocol-specific configuration, only IP addresses.
>
> Layer 2 mode does not require the IPs to be bound to the network
> interfaces of your worker nodes. It works by responding to ARP
> requests on your local network directly, to give the machine’s MAC
> address to clients.

In your ConfigMap we see:

```
data:
  config: |
    address-pools:
    - name: default
      protocol: layer2
      addresses:
      - 192.168.99.100-192.168.99.250
```

It gives MetalLB control over IPs from `192.168.99.100` to `192.168.99.250` and configures the Layer 2 mode. Notice that your minikube IP which is `192.168.99.102` is in the range defined above and thus you can access it via your browser.

This mechanic is well explained in the `MetalLB Layer 2 Configuration` section of [this guide](https://medium.com/@shoaib_masood/metallb-network-loadbalancer-minikube-335d846dfdbe):

> MetalLB contains two pieces of information, a protocol and range of IP
> addresses. In this configuration MetalLB is instructed to handout
> addresses from the 192.168.99.95/105, its our predefined range with
> respect to node IP. **In our case to get IP of our minikube we use
> minikube ip command and set range accordingly in config file.**

I recommend going through the whole guide to get a better understanding of the whole minikube + MetalLB concept.

Comment: @hochan Is my answer useful for you?

Comment: Thank you for answering first. 
It was very useful. However, the reason that the answer check was delayed is because I wanted to accumulate more knowledge and thank you with a quality answer. Actually, during the port connection process, a little problem occurred in the pv setting, so I could not experiment with the real environment.

Comment: In fact, I don't understand because I think the address part described in the matallb configmap should belong to the minikube ip, but the configuration I made is because the minikube ip belongs to the address part of the matallb configmap. After a little understanding, I would like to express my gratitude.